# Rendering layout with local variable in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, local-variables

In my rails controller I have an action that renders a specific layout:

```
  def registrations_for_user
      render layout: 'remote_modal', locals: { modal_title: I18n.t('organizations.enrolled_in_learning_item.title') }
    end
```

This layout needs the local `modal_title` to work, that is why I am passing it up there. Here's the layout :

```
<div class="relative px-4 w-full max-w-6xl md:h-auto">
  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="relative bg-white rounded-lg shadow dark:bg-gray-700">
    <!-- Modal header -->
    <div class="w-full">
      <div class="flex justify-between items-start p-5 rounded-t">
        <div class="w-full-0">
            <h3 class="text-lg font-semibold text-gray-900 dark:text-white">
              <%= modal_title %>
            </h3>
        </div>
        <i class="close-modal fas fa-times text-lg cursor-pointer"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Modal body -->
    <div class="px-6">
      <div class="w-full">
        <%= yield %> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However I keep getting :

```
NameError - undefined local variable or method `modal_title' for #<ActionView::Base:0x000000000656f8>:
  app/views/layouts/remote_modal.html.erb:9
```

Is it not possible to pass a local to a layout in rails ? Is there another way to do it ? I've read answers that suggested using a `@variable` but that does not seem like a clean way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define it in your controller
Depending on the route you could do something like

```
def local
@x = current_user.model.title #define your logic
end
```

then in your view `<%= @x %>`

Answer (score 0):

Use `locals` only in `partials`, inside the views, example:

```
<%= render partial: "form", locals: { zone: @zone } %>
```

In your case you can create a `helper` for `remote_modal_layout`: `app/helpers/remote_modal_helper.rb`

```rb
module RemoteModalHelper
  def modal_title 
    I18n.t("remote_modal.title.#{controller_name}.#{action_name}", default: 'Remote Modal')
  end
end
```

This helper contains the method `modal_title` that will work the way you need.

- Use `controller_name` + `action_name` to get the final `I18n` value!